# EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000000e7ffdefe in Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I'm getting the following error in Crashlytics

> LoginViewController.swift line 277
>   LoginViewController.textField(UITextField,
>   shouldChangeCharactersInRange : _NSRange, replacementString : String)
>   -> Bool

There's the code in my project:

```
   // MARK: - UITextFieldDelegate
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == txtSearch && string != "\n"{
        var substring: String = textField.text!
        substring = (substring as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
        self.searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring(substring)
    }
    return true;
}
```

This error ocurrs only sometimes

Comment: Which is line 277? What's the error?

Comment: The error is EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000000e7ffdefe like wrote in title

Comment: What's the human readable error and you still haven't pointed out which line is line 277.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are force unwrapping your `textField.text!` which may be nil. Try below code:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == txtSearch && string != "\n"{
        if let text = textField.text {
            let substring = (text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
            self.searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring(substring)
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: It seems correct...but I cant reproduce the error ...if I try to tap return with empty field, it's not crash...

Comment: If it is working for you and it helped you to fix your issue then please mark it as answer.

Comment: But I didn't reproduce the error on my device, only got the error in fabric..how could I reproduce it?

Comment: EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000000e7ffdefe with the code I've posted on my question...I never reproduced it only saw the log

Comment: Yes, thats what you want it right? You wanted it to be fixed or let it crash? What is your expectation by posting this question here?